# cannot conver sql query to string[] in android

Tags: android, cursor, illegalstateexception

i am trying to put strings from query to string[], but i gor an error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

here is my code:

```
private void getCitiesArray() {
    DonorDbHelper donorDbHelper = new DonorDbHelper(getActivity());
    String[] cityColumnName = new String[]{DonorContract.CitiesEntry.COLUMN_NAME};

    Cursor c = donorDbHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(DonorContract.CitiesEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            cityColumnName,
            null, null, null, null, null
    );
    c.moveToFirst();
    String[] test = null;
    int count = c.getCount();
    for (int i = 1; i < count ; i++){
        test[i-1] = c.getString(i);
        Log.d("111", "city #" + i + " - " + c.getString(i));
    }
    c.close();
}
```

dateBase:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        final String SQL_CREATE_CITIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + CitiesEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                CitiesEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                CitiesEntry.COLUMN_CITY_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                CitiesEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                CitiesEntry.COLUMN_REGION + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                "UNIQUE ( " + CitiesEntry.COLUMN_CITY_ID + " ) ON CONFLICT REPLACE);";

sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_CITIES_TABLE);
    }
```

why it happends and how to fix this?

Comment: please show Your database class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not looping the cursor rows but looping the columns. Furthermore,  you forgot to initialize the String array.

```
c.moveToFirst();
int count = c.getCount();
String[] strings = new String[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count ; ++i){
    strings[i] = c.getString(0);
    Log.d("111", "city #" + i + " - " + c.getString(i));
    c.moveToNext();
}
c.close();
```

Here I'm looping returned rows and save the first column value as a string.

Comment: yep, you are right!
thanks!

but in case: c.getString(0); it always return the same (first) string. 
and i need to put all datas, but not only first into string[]

Comment: can you help me how to returned all rows as a string?

Comment: @AndriyAntonov I've just shown you. This code adds the first column values from every row to a string array.

Comment: i am sorry, i miss c.moveToNext, and it return to me the same value...  Great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Try this:

```
Cursor cu=db.query(Helper.TABLE_NAME, column, null, null, null, null,null);
```